# Flutter BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' error

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

after many search and trying to resolve this problem finally I can't and when I try to run application on real phone I get this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\projects\flutter\elmustafa\android\settings.gradle'
>   (C:\Users\Mahdi
>   MyName.gradle\caches\6.5\scripts\bq3hllkgb26p0nrblf5gh8d37\settings6418c6d726070f323dbddda2aadc82ef).
>
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 3m 43s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed
> with exit code 1

in the first time I checked below line and I notice I didn't have that:

```
build.parallel=true
```

`gradle` version in `\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` is:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

and I cleaned cache folder(s):

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
rm -rf $PROJECT/.gradle/caches/ && rm -rf $PROJECT/build/
```

result of `flutter run --debug` command:

```
[ +115 ms] executing: [G:\android\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[+1338 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 1d9032c7e1d867f071f2277eb1673e8f9b0274e3
[   +1 ms] executing: [G:\android\flutter/] git tag --points-at 1d9032c7e1d867f071f2277eb1673e8f9b0274e3
[  +92 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 1d9032c7e1d867f071f2277eb1673e8f9b0274e3
[        ] 2.0.6
[  +62 ms] executing: [G:\android\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +46 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [G:\android\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +42 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +92 ms] executing: [G:\android\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +44 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] stable
[ +109 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +313 ms] executing: G:\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +64 ms] List of devices attached
           2XJDU17C14006203       device product:WAS-LX1A model:WAS_LX1A device:HWWAS-H transport_id:1
[  +10 ms] G:\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 2XJDU17C14006203 shell getprop
[  +95 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +133 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[  +78 ms] Found plugin connectivity at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\
[  +11 ms] Found plugin connectivity_for_web at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity_for_web-0.4.0\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin connectivity_macos at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity_macos-0.2.0\
[  +35 ms] Found plugin flutter_radio at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_radio-0.1.8\
[  +37 ms] Found plugin path_provider at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-2.0.2\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin path_provider_linux at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_linux-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin path_provider_macos at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_macos-2.0.0\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin path_provider_windows at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_windows-2.0.1\
[  +16 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-2.0.6\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_linux at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_linux-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_macos at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_macos-2.0.0\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_web at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_web-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_windows at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_windows-2.0.0\
[   +7 ms] Found plugin sqflite at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-2.0.0+3\
[  +13 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-6.0.6\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_linux at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_linux-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_macos-2.0.0\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_web at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_web-2.0.1\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_windows at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_windows-2.0.0\
[ +163 ms] Found plugin connectivity at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin connectivity_for_web at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity_for_web-0.4.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin connectivity_macos at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity_macos-0.2.0\
[  +16 ms] Found plugin flutter_radio at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_radio-0.1.8\
[  +25 ms] Found plugin path_provider at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-2.0.2\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin path_provider_linux at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_linux-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin path_provider_macos at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_macos-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin path_provider_windows at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_windows-2.0.1\
[  +14 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-2.0.6\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_linux at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_linux-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_macos at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_macos-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_web at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_web-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_windows at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_windows-2.0.0\
[   +7 ms] Found plugin sqflite at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-2.0.0+3\
[   +9 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-6.0.6\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_linux at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_linux-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_macos-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_web at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_web-2.0.1\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_windows at G:\android\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_windows-2.0.0\
[  +28 ms] Generating C:\projects\flutter\example\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +89 ms] ro.hardware = hi6250
[   +1 ms] ro.build.characteristics = default
[  +69 ms] Initializing file store
[  +14 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[   +6 ms] complete
[   +7 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on WAS LX1A in debug mode...
[   +8 ms] G:\android\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev G:\android\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
G:\android\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names --experimental-emit-debug-metadata --output-dill
C:\Users\MAHDIP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.e97f471f\flutter_tool.3f85af30\app.dill --packages C:\projects\flutter\example\.dart_tool\package_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false
-Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill build\cache.dill.track.dill
[  +24 ms] executing: G:\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 2XJDU17C14006203 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +20 ms] <- compile package:example/main.dart
[  +89 ms] --------- beginning of main
           06-12 20:49:38.040 I/TrafficMonitor( 1028): gettimer:interval=2000
[  +17 ms] executing: G:\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[  +29 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 30.0.4-6686687
           Installed as G:\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[  +11 ms] executing: G:\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +93 ms] Building APK
[  +39 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[  +11 ms] Using gradle from C:\projects\flutter\example\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +2 ms] C:\projects\flutter\example\android\gradlew.bat mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx.
[  +16 ms] executing: [C:\projects\flutter\example\android/] C:\projects\flutter\example\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64
-Ptarget=C:\projects\flutter\example\lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[+1504 ms] Welcome to Gradle 6.5!
[   +2 ms] Here are the highlights of this release:
[  +30 ms]  - Experimental file-system watching
[   +1 ms]  - Improved version ordering
[   +1 ms]  - New samples
[   +1 ms] For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/release-notes.html
[ +937 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +5 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\projects\flutter\example\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Mahdi
MyName\.gradle\caches\6.5\scripts\bq3hllkgb26p0nrblf5gh8d37\settings6418c6d726070f323dbddda2aadc82ef).
[   +2 ms] > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60
[   +1 ms] * Try:
[   +1 ms] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +3 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +1 ms] BUILD FAILED in 1s
[ +615 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 3.1s)
[+15239 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 20,123ms.
[   +5 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:644:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[ +257 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 254ms
[   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +2 ms] Shutdown hook priority 4
[   +6 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
```

`java` version:

```
java version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried a lower version of the JDK? Maybe 11? I've seen people having success by downgrading the JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading `JDK` that cause resolve this problem and i can build `apk` and `iphone` release application

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue but downgrading jdk resolved the issue.

I installed "jdk-16.0.2_windows-x64_bin" in my computer and uninstalling that one and installing "jdk-8u301-windows-x64" resolved the issue.

[Install jdk-8u301-windows-x64](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)

Please note that when installing "jdk-8u301-windows-x64" you need to create an account in oracle.

Once done restart your computer and then "run flutter" you will be good to go

Answer (score 0):

This error will generally occur due to cache override of gradle.
clean the cache

cd android
./gradlew clean

or you can manually clean gradle cache.
Go to C:\Users\ganesh.gradle\caches
and deleted all cache from there.

after cleaning cache.
you can upgrade Gradle.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KegUu.png)

then run your project. if necessary then only make change on build.gradle file
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COecO.png)